# p-Value for regression on the whole population

Tags: statistics

I would like to know what is the meaning of the p-Value statistic when I make a linear regression with the full population (and not a small sample of it).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Full population implies that statistical inference is out the window. But you could still test the null hypothesis that the response values are randomly distributed between conditions without relation to other predictors. The p-value of the F-statistic can be interpreted as an estimate of the proportion of permutations with an F-value larger than the expected value when H0 is true. In case that proportion is small we reject the idea that the response is unrelated to the predictors. 
See: J. Faraway, Practical Regression and Anova using R